# Angular 2 - Update view when variable changes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a button on my nav bar (app.component.html) that I want to only show when the user is logged in.
This is my current approach that does not work for obvious reasons explained later. I want to find out how I can modify it to work.

Inside my app.component.html, I have the following button

```
<button *ngIf="isCurrentUserExist">MyButton</button>
```

Inside my app.component.ts, I am trying to bound the variable isCurrentUserExist to a function that returns true if the user exists.
I believe this is the problem because this code is only executed once at OnInit as oppose to somehow keeping the view updated

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isCurrentUserExist = this.userService.isCurrentUserExist();    
}
```

For reference, inside my UserService.ts

```
export class UserService {

    private currentUser: User

    constructor(private http: Http,private angularFire: AngularFire) { }

    getCurrentUser(): User {
        return this.currentUser
    }

    setCurrentUser(user: User) {
        this.currentUser = user;
    }

    isCurrentUserExist(): boolean {
        if (this.currentUser) {
        return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

A bit more information about my app...
Upon start up when the user does not exist, I have a login screen (login component). 
When the user logs in, it goes to firebase and grab the user information (async) and store it to my user service via

```
setCurrentUser(user: User)
```

So at this point, I like to update the button in my nav bar (which exists in app.component.html) and show the button.

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let's try this:
using BehaviorSubject

**UserService.ts**

```
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class UserService {

    private currentUser: User;
    public loggedIn: Subject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(private http: Http,private angularFire: AngularFire) { }

    getCurrentUser(): User {
        return this.currentUser
    }

    setCurrentUser(user: User) { // this method must call when async process - grab firebase info - finished
        this.currentUser = user;
        this.loggedIn.next(true);
    }

    isCurrentUserExist(): boolean {
        if (this.currentUser) {
        return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.loggedIn.subscribe(response => this.isCurrentUserExist = response);    
}
```

Comment: Hi Tiep. Thanks for this. It does work very well. I was thinking along the line of event emitter before. However, I didnt like to use it unless I'm desperate because it feels like signals flying through the air waiting for someone to grab it (sort of like push notification). This BehaviorSubject does feel like some kind of event emitter as well? Do you know if there is another approach (for learning purpose)

Comment: you could create custom event emitter system (maybe base on observable), then when somewhere, you could subscribe to some kind of event like 'user.login' (Ionic 2 have own event system). whenever event fired, you will get value - payload - to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

in `app.component.ts` you are assigned value from function once. So it will never change. To resolve this problem and to real time update use assign function instance of boolean variable `this.isCurrentUserExist = this.userService.isCurrentUserExist;`. And in view change change `*ngIf` expression as function `isCurrentUserExist()`.